# Where is virtualenvwrapper.sh?

Tags: apt, python, dpkg

I don't know what's more embarrassing: that I don't know how to go about finding the answer to this question myself, or that it has to be asked at all in the first place, but...

> where does `apt-get` put the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script after it installs `virtualenvwrapper`?

I'm at wits' end...

```
% sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
...
% rehash
% which virtualenvwrapper.sh
virtualenvwrapper.sh not found
% which virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper not found
% find / -path /media -prune -o -name virtualenvwrapper.sh
/media
% dpkg-query -L virtualenvwrapper | grep 'virtualenvwrapper\.sh'
% sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
virtualenvwrapper is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I've run out of things to try: `apt-get` says `virtualenvwrapper` is already installed, but I can't find any sign of `virtualenvwrapper.sh` anywhere.

UPDATE: Well, I just discovered that the file

```
/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper
```

...looks very much like `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.  I can't tell whether this file was put there by `apt-get` when I ran `apt-get install virtualenvwrapper` (the file's mdate is several months ago), but if it was, then I'm mystified by the apparent stupidity of the arrangement...  For one thing, not everyone uses `bash` (I happen to use `zsh`).  For another, one may want to run `virtualenvwrapper.sh` at times other than startup...  I'm sure I'm missing something major here, but on the surface, it sure looks like the `apt-get` installation of `virtualenvwrapper` is plain retarded...  At any rate, it wasted about three hours of my time...

Comment: Another zsh-user here... might as well stop using the official package for virtualenvwrapper, fewer surprises that way!

Comment: You can source `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` in zsh as well. It works fine as-is.

Comment: @JimStewart I can do lots of things. Point of a package is that I don't have to.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From `/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/README.Debian`:

```
In contrast to the information in
/usr/share/doc/virtualenvwrapper/en/html/index.html this package installs
virtualenvwrapper.sh as /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper.

Virtualenvwrapper is enabled if you install the package bash-completion and
enable bash completion support in /etc/bash.bashrc or your ~/.bashrc.

If you only want to use virtualenvwrapper you may just add

 source /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

to your ~/.bashrc.
```

Yes, it's a bit hard to find :D

Comment: What about `zsh` users? Great, another package that behaves differently on each OS. I think a `sudo apt-get purge virtualenvwrapper` and `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper` is in order.

Comment: You can source `/etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper` in zsh as well. It works fine as-is.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, the script's location is:

```
/usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

So if you've installed `virtualenvwrapper` with the package manager, you must add the following lines into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

---

Also, remember to reload your `~/.bashrc` with:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

If everything worked well, then you'll be able to run `mkvirtualenv` like:

```
mkvirtualenv --python="/usr/bin/python3" venv_name
```

Comment: This is currently the right solution